# A theory which denies the existence of a truth predicate

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, metamathematics

Is there a paper or other reference that explores the implications of a theory that *denying* the existence of a truth predicate in its own language (perhaps based on ZFC or PA)?

I know that a theory that proves itself inconsistent will prove that it has no truth predicate, but I'm looking more for examples like `ZFC+there is no truth predicate for set theory` (which is the same as `ZFC + no model of set theory is sound`).

Comment: How would you formulate it? There are several distinct things going under the name “truth predicate”, but generally they are described by an infinite schema, hence you can’t negate it. Anyway, the proof of Tarski’s undefinability theorem gives you a sense in which *every* theory denies the existence of its truth predicate.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek https://mathoverflow.net/a/273121/65915 shows a finite construction of a truth predicate. Also, I'm thinking in terms of second of "there is no function that determines truth" (which is not implied by Tarski's theorem) as opposed to "there is no *definable* function that determines truth (which is).

Comment: A truth predicate (in the linked sense) is a proper class. How do you intend to universally quantify in ZFC (or in PA) over proper classes that are not definable? The theory has no means of referring to them.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oh hmm, I guess formulating such a theory is harder than I thought. I'm going to ask a separate question about it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek [Here it is.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275271/65915)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Okay, here is an example: https://mathoverflow.net/a/275276/65915